# Nginx can't be accessed from outside?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, router, port-forwarding

I got a server set up. It's perfect from 127.0.0.1, but if I try from my "real" ip it loads forever, and then chrome says "Can't connect." Basically it does not allow external access.

I'm behind a router, on an Ubuntu 10.10. I don't know if I have any firewall, but I haven't installed any. 
I think it's the router. It's a Thomson TCW710. I'm not sure that I have port-forwarded port 80 correctly.

It's not only nginx.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind figured it out. 
It's ufw.

```
sh@SH:~$ sudo ufw disable 
[sudo] password for sh: 
WARN: uid is 0 but '/etc' is owned by 1000
WARN: uid is 0 but '/' is owned by 1000
WARN: uid is 0 but '/usr' is owned by 1000
Firewall stopped and disabled on system startup
```